# Alternative to ipfs in hashgraph implementation

Tags: distributed-system, ipfs

Is there any alternative to ipfs for implementing hashgraph ?
Which is the most suitable technology to handle communication between nodes in  a hashgraph implementation over a distributed network?

Answer (score 0):

I think that best way is to use `swirlds java sdk` to handle the communication between the nodes themselves, and use `websocket` to communicate to that app from your application.

The `public hadera ledger` will have natively built in `file sharing` apps alongside `crypto`.

There is also  [unofficial `golang` implementation](https://github.com/babbleio/babble) , dont think `ipfs` is used there at all but not sure how file sharing is implemented. Have a look.